# Bijection from the set of odd natural numbers to integers

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How to construct  a bijection $f: A\to \Bbb{Z}$ where $A$ is the set of odd natural numbers?

Comment: Find a method that would list all the numbers in each set.

Comment: Have you ever heard of Cantor's diagonal argument? that should give you some inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An odd natural number can be written as $2n-1$, $n \in \mathbf N$, hence 
$$ A \to \mathbf N, \quad 2n-1\mapsto n $$
is a bijection. Now we map $\mathbf N$ to $\mathbf Z$. Let $n$ a natural number, if it is even, say $n = 2k$, we map it to $k-1$, if it is odd, say $n = 2k-1$, we map it to $-k$. This gives the bijection
$$ \mathbf N \to \mathbf Z, \quad n \mapsto \begin{cases} 
  k-1 & n = 2k\\ -k & n = 2k-1 \end{cases} 
$$ 
Concatenating both maps, we have the bijection $A \to \mathbf Z$ 
$$ 2n-1 \mapsto \begin{cases} 
  k-1 & n = 2k\\ -k & n = 2k-1 \end{cases} 
$$